# python selenium can't interact with input element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to put my name in an input field. It seems like a simple thing that selenium is built to do, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signUpName16"]')
name.send_keys('Josh')
```

I know the driver works because I've been able to click other elements. I know the xpath is right because I copied it from chrome inspector. The error I get is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I've seen people say to try clicking or clearing elements so I've tried that too, but that still failed.

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signUpName16"]')
name.click()
name.send_keys('Josh')
```

yields this for the name.click() line

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different things that can be going wrong here. If the `input` is not fully loaded, then it will throw this exception if you try to `send_keys` before it is ready. We can invoke `WebDriverWait` on the `input` element to ensure it is fully loaded before sending keys to it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'signUpName')]")))

input.send_keys("Josh")
```

If this still throws the exception, we can instead try to set the `input` value through Javascript:

```
input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'signUpName')]")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'Josh';", input)
```

If neither of these solutions work, we may need to see some of the HTML on the page you are working with to see if there's any other issue happening here.

Comment: IMO, the _ID_ is dynamic and you need to adjust your locator.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any HTML provided. I thought maybe `//input[contains(@id, 'signUpName')]` might work here too -- I'll change it to that as it is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

**ElementNotInteractableException** occurs when

- Element is not displayed,
- Element is out of screen ,
- Some time element is hidden or
- Behind to another element

Please refer below code to solve this issue:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")


    driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
    driver.get("your url")

    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='signUpName16']")))
    actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@id,signUpName')]"))) # if your signUpName16 element is dynamic then use contains method to locate your element
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```